# Как поместить $_POST в регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

К примеру, `$_POST['phone'] = '875'`

```
$fileArr = file('classifieds.txt');
foreach($fileArr as $key=>$str){
    if( preg_match("'~" . $_POST['phone'] . "~'", $fileArr[$key]) ){
        echo $fileArr[$key] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Как правильно вписать переменную в preg_match, чтобы получилось `preg_match('~875~', $fileArr[$key])`, - я с кавычками совсем запутался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто:

```
preg_match("~{$_POST['phone']}~", $fileArr[$key])
```

Comment: Никак не мог найти в интернете про фигурные кавычки вокруг переменной...

Comment: А что получится, если на вход придёт нечто вроде `(что-то` ? Или `что-то~` ? Динамические шаблоны нужно экранировать : `preg_quote($_POST['phone'], '~');`

Comment: @Эдуард, спасибо за замечание! Для меня это актуально!